# NuxtJS Event Bus Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js, vue-props

I have created an `eventBus` in a plugins folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
      
const eventBus = {}
    
eventBus.install = function (Vue) {
    Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue()
}
    
Vue.use(eventBus)
```

I have Updated my nuxt config file.

```
// Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
    '~/plugins/bus'
  ],
```

I have two card components on a homepage component.  I want when I click the link on the card to take the user to another nuxt-linked page and set the data on that page to either true or false in the `created()` to conditionally render the data.  I have set on the two different cards:

```
 <nuxt-link to="/tours-and-seminars" v-on:click="changeTourStatus">
      Click Here for More Information
    </nuxt-link>
  </div>
</template>
     <script>
export default {
  methods: {
    changeTourStatus: function () {
      this.$bus.$emit("changeTourStatus", true);
    },
  },
  name: "ToursCard",
};
</script>
```

The other card is the inverse of this setting it to false.

On my other page I have a simple v-if that if data: tours = true render one, if not render the other item on the page.  I then have the below in the created() to change the "tours" data and then the page.

```
 created() {
this.$bus.$on("changeTourStatus", (data) => {
  console.log(data);
  this.tours = data;
});
```

},
};

I would hope loads with the the correct conditions to render either the one item or the other based on whatever the created() changes it to.  But at the moment I am getting nothing show.

I am unsure if it is the bus I have added not working or if it is how I am sending the data.  The console.log in the created() is returning nothing at the moment I can see in the dev tools.

Comment: I really recommend using something else than an eventBus because nowadays (with Vue3), you can either have a singleton and handle this with composables or be using Vuex/Pinia with the possibility of having a great DX regarding debugging via the devtools. An event bus is none of the above, it's just an ugly hack that may be used as a store but with no benefits at all. So, I may highly recommend using a proper store like Vuex. Not sure why some people are asking for an event bus still, there is probably a tutorial somewhere who recommended this at some point I guess.

Comment: I recommend XState :)

Comment: @Forbidden state machine != store.

Comment: State Machine still can handle data

Comment: @Forbidden still not the same use-case.